# Appveyor Linux Python fails

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, appveyor, tox

I want to run tests of my python project on [Appveyor](https://www.appveyor.com) under Linux.

#### 1. Run tox without install (fails)

I have tried without installing tox. [Here is the appveyor.yml](https://github.com/raczben/pylinx/blob/b00b712f73f3c3342486b762335cf9c7f11e36d5/appveyor.yml):

```
# appveyor.yml
---

image:
  - Ubuntu

build: off

test_script:
  - tox
```

[My build fails](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/raczben/pylinx/builds/29153015). It says:

```
/opt/appveyor/build-agent/bash-shell.sh: line 62: tox: command not found
```

---

#### 2. Install tox (fails)

OK, let's install tox first... [Here is my new appveyor.yml](https://github.com/raczben/pylinx/blob/d050044b8e4472a2bd102b59e4263d3336be4bbf/appveyor.yml), which is based on [this guide](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/lang/python/). (I've just added the Ubuntu image.)

```
# appveyor.yml
---

environment:
  matrix:
  - TOXENV: py36

image:
  - Ubuntu

build: off

install:
  - pip install tox

test_script:
  - tox
```

However, [build fails](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/raczben/pylinx/builds/29153668) again. It says:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyparsing.py'
```

**How to run tox on Appveyor under Ubuntu?**

Comment: Try `pip install tox --user`

Comment: However there are many workarounds to run tests under Linux on Appveyor, it is a known fact that Appveyor is a Windows hub. Finally I migrated my tests to [travis](https://travis-ci.org/raczben/pylinx/jobs/617727784), and now it passes. But the question is still open, because travis does not support Windows 100%, so I want to run my tests both Win and Linux.

Comment: I run Linux tests at Travis and w32 tests at AppVeyor. For free software projects Travis gives away **much more** free resources!

Answer (score 0):

Either use `sudo` to become root:

```
sudo pip install tox
```

or install in your `$HOME`:

```
pip install tox --user
```

and add `~/.local/bin` to `$PATH`; or run `~/.local/bin/tox` directly.

Comment: Am I sudo on Appveyor?